# ExpressJS - Serve both universal Nuxt app and AngularJS SPA

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a blog project with this structure:

- server - written in Node/Express
- admin - AngularJS SPA
- public - AngularJS SPA (for the moment)

The admin and public parts have the same domain, but the admin part uses a different subdomain, which allows me to serve the app like this in Express:

```js
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  var firstIndex = req.get('host').indexOf('.');
  var subdomain = req.get('host').substr(0, firstIndex).toLowerCase();
  if (subdomain === '') {
    // Public part
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
  } else if (subdomain.indexOf('admin') !== -1) {
    // Admin part
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../admin/js', 'index.html'));
  } else {
    // Static files
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', req.url));
  }
});
```

This solution works fine. It captures all requests and serve the right index.html for each subdomain.

**PROBLEM** -> 
I would like to pass the public part of the project in VueJS, and specifically using **Nuxt** to benefit from server-side rendering. I'm new to Nuxt so don't understand yet every details of this framework.

I saw it is possible to serve an [universal app with Express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48708375/9013688), but I have no idea of how to make it compatible with my current solution.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's recommended to call `nuxt.render` at the end of your middlewares since it will handle the rendering of your web application and won't call `next()` - https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render/

First, call next() in the "Public part".

Second, add the nuxt middleware below.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  var firstIndex = req.get('host').indexOf('.');
  var subdomain = req.get('host').substr(0, firstIndex).toLowerCase();
  if (subdomain === '') {
    // Public part, call next() to use the nuxt middleware!
    next();
  } else if (subdomain.indexOf('admin') !== -1) {
    // Admin part
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../admin/js', 'index.html'));
  } else {
    // Static files
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', req.url));
  }
});

// The nuxt middleware
app.use(nuxt.render);
```

---

Another example that also works.

```
// If Public part, response Nuxt server render app.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  var subdomain = req.get('host').substr(0, firstIndex).toLowerCase();
  if (subdomain === '') {
    // Public part, call nuxt.render middleware
    nuxt.render(req, res, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

// admin / static files
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  var firstIndex = req.get('host').indexOf('.');
  var subdomain = req.get('host').substr(0, firstIndex).toLowerCase();
  if (subdomain.indexOf('admin') !== -1) {
    // Admin part
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../admin/js', 'index.html'));
  } else {
    // Static files
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', req.url));
  }
});
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I used express static files to do what you're asking, if you want to read more, you can do it at http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

First of all, in your "app.js" file you have to add this two lines:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname +'../public'));
app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname +'../admin/js'));
```

After that, you have to check the index.html from both front-end projects, and make sure each of them has the correct base href. For example,

public/index.html should have:

```
<base href="/public/">
```

admin/index.html should have:

```
<base href="/admin/">
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: Thank you Felipe but it is that I have already (to manage to single page application) and it works perfectly. I would like to pass one SPA into an universal app (which use server side rendering) and my doubt is: how to configure my server to do this?